# How to install editable dependency via yarn

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, yarnpkg

Is it possible to install a yarn dependency as an editable dependency?

I'm looking for something like python pip's:

`pip install -e`

For local development of a library. My goal is to see changes in a package I'm developing while simultaneously using it in another package.

Comment: If you mean local development on a package you're developing while simultaneously using it in another package, maybe you're looking for [npm link](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/link.html) and the yarn equivalent [yarn link](https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/cli/link/). If you're trying to edit a package that was installed from a package manager, then you could also try [patch-package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/patch-package).

Comment: Yes, that's the idea. Updated question for clarity, thanks!

Comment: @Khauri add your comment as an answer please :)

Answer (score 1):

Like Khauri in the comments, you can achieve this using `npm link` or `yarn link`, which creates a [symbolic link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link) of your local package and allows a similar experience to editable installs in Python (`pip install -e`).

In `npm` (and also in `yarn`), this is a two-step process:

1. In the root of your project (where `package.json` is located), you can use `npm link` to add the package to the global register.
2. Then, you can do `npm link PACKAGE_NAME` to add the symlinked package to your local `node_modules`.

You can use `npm list` to see all installed packages, and if it says `extraneous -> /path/to/package` next to the package name, then it is successfully linked to your local source code!

Answer (score -1):

You can directly edit the files in `node_modules` and changes there are reflected immediately, but also overwritten when yarn decides to update the module. Note, that some files need to be built first or might be a bit tricky to edit (minified / transpiled build artefacts). You can also install the module directly from GitHub, if this is easier for your development process.

Apart from that, there is no such thing as "editable" dependencies in npm / yarn.